# Is this weighing cell arduino compatible?

Tags: arduino

I've purchased a TE FX29 weighing cell [pdf link](https://www.mouser.dk/datasheet/2/418/5/ENG_DS_FX29_A5-1609196.pdf).

It comes in three different (output) versions: mV, amplified and serial (I2C) -- I've bought the amplified version.

The specs tells me that the supply voltage should be 4.75v-5.25v and the operating current 3mA

The output should be analog 0.5v-4.5v

I think this should be okay to attach directly to 5V/GND and A0/GND an arduino nano? ...I'm a bit unsure about the 3mA input however, as the Arduino can supply quite a bit more than that (I believe).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about interpreting electrical specifications, not a programming problem

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about software.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and tried it out --- works fine.
5V arduino out to the red FX29 wire
GND arduino to the black FX29 wire
A0 arduino analog input to the yellow FX29 wire

...readings between cirka 107 (unloaded) and up (to 1023 obviously) -- I have not calibrated this with any weights yet, but with a range of about 25 lbs I should get something useful from 0-10 kg with a resolution of about 10 grams.

Answer (score 0):

Be advised, that the amplified version is somewhat restricted in range and highly dependent upon the voltage --- the non-amplified or serial versions may be a better bet